# Metric space is open

Tags: real-analysis

> For any $n=1,2,...$ and any $a\in \mathbb{R}$, the subset of $E^n$
>   given by $\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in E^n : x_1>a\}$ is open.

I don't know why it's open?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Given $x = (x_1, ..., x_n) \in E^n$, consider the (open) ball of radius $$\frac{|x_1 - a|}{2} > 0$$ around $x$. Do you see why the ball is contained in $E^n$?

Comment: I don't have the slightest clue.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The mapping $f:(x_1, \dots,x_n) \mapsto x_1-a$ is continuous, and $E=f^{-1}(0,\infty).$